# Запоминание состояние дерева при переходе на другую страницу Angular 6

Tags: angular, дерево, state

В общем в проекте есть дерево, выводящее данные. Но допустим пользователь выбрал какой-то элемент из этого дерева и перешел по ссылке этого элемента на другую страницу, там посидел некоторое время и после нажал кнопку "назад" что бы вернуться обратно, но дерево свернуто. Как можно реализовать что бы в дереве была открыта именно та ветвь до элемента по ссылке которого перешел пользователь?

Любые предложения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Angular 6 есть класс Location, который может подменить текущий url адрес на нужный нам. Таким образом можно подменить адрес и добавить к нему параметр, который будет отвечать за id элемента который выбрал пользователь и при переходе назад (в истории хранится подмененный нами адрес) пользователь попадет на страницу, на которой мы можем считать параметр и зная его открыть нужную ветвь до нужного элемента.

Пример использования:

```
import { Location } from "@angular/common";

constructor(
    public location: Location
  ) {}

this.location.path(); - Текущий URL
this.location.replaceState('/новый url/','параметры'); - Подменяет URL
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону LocalStorage, SessionStorage или Cookies https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage 
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie